# Does UISlider (and other UI elements) have inherit gesture recognizers

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I was just curious if a UISlider had an inherit pan gesture recognizer in it, or if UI elements are separate from gesture recognizers.  My guess is separate.

Basically I have another method developed by one of our consultants who is no longer with us that takes in a gesture recognizer of a scrollView to get its locationInView property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gesture recognizers have existed for some time, although they were only made public in iOS 4.0. The `UIScrollView` gesture recognizers that are actually used by the scroll view were only made accessible through the public SDK in iOS 5.0, although you could get hold of them in previous iOS versions through some code trickery.

It's possible that a `UISlider` uses gesture recognizers under the hood, or it may just use the `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded`, etc methods. Either way, it's not something that is exposed to you. It would in theory be possible to find this out through experimentation, but if you start using functionality that isn't exposed in the public SDK you run the risk that it will break in a newer iOS version (this has happened in the past).